# How can I create Organizational Units recursively on Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, organizational-unit

I'm writing a Powershell script to populate all the company users to a Active Directory from a CSV file.

The script uses the Powershell command `New-ADUser` and it should know, for every user, where is the path to add them, for example:

```
"OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso"
```

The problem is: this Active Directory doesn't have any users yet, so there's no Organizational Units created, and whenever I run the script, if the path doesn't exists, the user is not created.

I've looked up for a command to create Organizational Units, like `New-ADOrganizationalUnit` or `dsadd`, however they do not support recursive creations, like

```
"OU=Helpdesk,OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso"
```

if

```
"OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso"
```

does not exist yet.

Is there any way of doing that using *New-ADOrganizationalUnit*?

Thanks

Comment: You could just have it check at each level and create it if it doesn't exist right?  Instead of trying to create the whole OU path in one command.

Comment: Sure, I could do that, in fact that was my plan B, but if there's a "native" way to do that, my script will be simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [Mike](https://serverfault.com/users/88251/mike), you'll need to step through each level in the tree and test for the existence of the OUs ancestors, and then create the ones that doesn't exist, from the top-most level and down.

As long as `New-ADOrganisationalUnit` does not have a -Recurse parameter, this is the most elegant way I could think of:

```
function New-OrganizationalUnitFromDN
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param(
        [string]$DN
    )

    # A regex to split the DN, taking escaped commas into account
    $DNRegex = '(?<![\\]),'

    # Array to hold each component
    [String[]]$MissingOUs = @()

    # We'll need to traverse the path, level by level, let's figure out the number of possible levels 
    $Depth = ($DN -split $DNRegex).Count

    # Step through each possible parent OU
    for($i = 1;$i -le $Depth;$i++)
    {
        $NextOU = ($DN -split $DNRegex,$i)[-1]
        if($NextOU.IndexOf("OU=") -ne 0 -or [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$NextOU"))
        {
            break
        }
        else
        {
            # OU does not exist, remember this for later
            $MissingOUs += $NextOU
        }
    }

    # Reverse the order of missing OUs, we want to create the top-most needed level first
    [array]::Reverse($MissingOUs)

    # Prepare common parameters to be passed to New-ADOrganizationalUnit
    $PSBoundParameters.Remove('DN')

    # Now create the missing part of the tree, including the desired OU
    foreach($OU in $MissingOUs)
    {
        $newOUName = (($OU -split $DNRegex,2)[0] -split "=")[1]
        $newOUPath = ($OU -split $DNRegex,2)[1]

        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $newOUName -Path $newOUPath @PSBoundParameters
    }
}
```

Usage using WHATIF

```
# The desired resulting OU DN  
$DN = "OU=Helpdesk,OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso"
New-OrganizationalUnitFromDN $DN -WhatIf
```

Without WHATIF

```
# The desired resulting OU DN  
$DN = "OU=Helpdesk,OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso"
New-OrganizationalUnitFromDN $DN
```

It will break if there are non-existing non-OU containers in the path.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution to my script and I'm having some issues. Does your solution should be working for itself? I can't see any attribution for the $OU variable, am I missing something? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Attribution? I'm not sure I understand. The `$OU` variable in the last block is assigned from `foreach($OU in $MissingOUs)`. Since we reversed the order of the `$MissingOUs` array already, It will have these values assigned (in order) 1) "OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso", 2) "OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso" and finally 3) "OU=HelpDesk,OU=IT Dept,OU=Users,DC=local,DC=contoso". Try to substitute `Write-Host` for New-ADOrganizationalUnit to see it

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing terribly wrong, but copy and pasting your code and changing only the `New-ADOrganizationalUnit` to `Write-Host` not works for me. I'm new to powershell so i'm having some trouble to find the problem. it seems the problem is in the     `if($NextOU.IndexOf("OU=") -ne 0 -or [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$NextOU/"))`    line.

Comment: @MaurícioMota Join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16813/discussion-between-mathias-r-jessen-and-mauricio-mota) and I'll try to help you out

Answer (score 1):

The output of `$NextOU.IndexOf("OU=")` is case sensitive and will return -1 for all lowercase `ou=`
try: `$NextOU.IndexOf("OU=",[StringComparison]"CurrentCultureIgnoreCase")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach; it is much simpler:
https://dimitri.janczak.net/2016/04/20/recursive-ou-creation-with-powershell/

Comment: your answer is unclear and lack of the description, please add some description about link provided in answer, also please refer [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to write a good answer.